# In Perl, how can I skip an empty key when traversing a hash?

Tags: perl, hash, traversal

This is my problem, I'm not very knowledgeable in Perl, and I have this function that needs to be fixed.

When this function `deviceModelMenu()` is called, the CLI displays the following text:

```
The following models are available
==================================================
1.   
2. Cisco1240 
3. Catalyst3750 
4. Catalyst3650 
5. HP2524
```

The first item is empty, which is wrong, and I need to fix that, the piece of code that displays this menu is:

```
my $features = shift;
print "=" x 50, "\n";
print "The following models are available\n";
print "=" x 50, "\n";
my $i=1;
foreach (keys %{$features->{features}[0]->{deviceModel}})
{
    print "$i. $_ \n";
    $i++;
}
```

If I add the following line:

```
warn Dumper($features->{features}[0]->{deviceModel});
```

It dumps this:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'deviceModel' => {
                         '' => {
                                 'cfg' => []
                               },
                         'Cisco1240' => {
                                        'cfg' => [
                                                 'cisco1240feature.cfg'
                                               ]
                                      },
                         'Catalyst3750' => {
                                           'cfg' => [
                                                    'catalyst3750feature.cfg'
                                                  ]
                                         },
                         'Catalyst3650' => {
                                           'cfg' => [
                                                    'catalyst3650feature.cfg'
                                                  ]
                                         },
                         'HP2524' => {
                                     'cfg' => [
                                              'hp2524feature.cfg'
                                            ]
                                   }
                       }
    };
```

As you may notice, the first item is indeed empty. I added the following line to skip it, and just print the rest of the info:

```
if ($_ eq '') {
        shift;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to <del>work</del> do what I want. I want to skip the item if it's empty.

Comment: Don't say ***Shift a list in Perl doesn't work, looking for alternative*** unless you mean it. Choose a descriptive and meaningful title for your question. The whole point of SO is to provide a way for others to find answers to programming questions. Above all, don't hurl insults willy-nilly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, shifting [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) (implicit argument to shift in main program) nor shifting [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@_) (implicit argument of [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) in a function) are not going to help you, because you are not printing either of them.

You can either:

1. Not add the `''` entry in the first place (depends on how it's generated)
2. Remove the `''` entry before printing:

   ```
   delete $features->{features}[0]->{deviceModel}->{''};
   ```
3. Don't print the entry:

   ```
   if($_ eq '') {
       next;
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if($_ ne '') {
       print "$i. $_ \n";
       $i++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (keys %{$features->{features}[0]->{deviceModel}})
{
    next unless length($_);
    print "$i. $_ \n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This alternative seems more elegant than the one I proposed

Comment: Perhaps `next unless /\S/;` might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $devices = {
    'deviceModel' => {
         '' => { 'cfg' => [] },
         'Cisco1240' => { 'cfg' => ['cisco1240feature.cfg' ] },
         'Catalyst3750' => { 'cfg' => [ 'catalyst3750feature.cfg' ]},
         'Catalyst3650' => { 'cfg' => [ 'catalyst3650feature.cfg' ]},
         'HP2524' => { 'cfg' => [ 'hp2524feature.cfg' ]},
     }
};


{
    my $item = 1;
    for my $d (grep length, keys %{ $devices->{deviceModel} }) {
        printf "%2d. %s\n", $item++, $d;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 1. Catalyst3750
 2. Cisco1240
 3. Catalyst3650
 4. HP2524
```

Comment: +1 for use of grep inside for loop... that tickles my aesthetic bone.